# How do I make all the answers to questions in HTML produce one result?

Tags: html

I want to make all the answers to questions or the user preferences lead to one result please help. I want to do something like how Craigslist gives you preferences and leads you to one result. such as how do i link these two questions :

are you a bird?
        
         
        yes
        no

Can you fly
    
         
        yes
        no

so that if the user was to choose yes to both it would give the result of "your a penguin"

Comment: What do you mean? also this isn't a code writing service, nobody will do that for you. 

You have to include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.][1]
 
[How do I ask a good question?][2]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: Please provide some codes what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

please note that I'm only giving you this answer because I'm super bored since I'm debugging a program that basically just needs to crush numbers, please elaborate your question more and include what you tried yourself next time.

in javascript:

```
var q1 = true // question 1 answer (yes = true, no = false)
var q2 = false // question 1 answer (yes = true, no = false)

if(q1 == true && q2 == true) {

    //your actions here, for example
    alert("you are a parrot");

} else if(q1 == true && q2 == false) {

    //your actions here, for example
    alert("you are a penguin");

} else if(q1 == false && q2 == true) {

    //your actions here, for example
    alert("you are a military apache helicopter");

} else //last option, so q1 == false and q2 == false {

    //your actions here, for example
    alert("you are a human");

}
```

remember: this is just a hard coded example, if you want a user to make a quiz thing like this himself, you should probably loop through all the values and read them out of an array or something...